# Angular Material - Use Progress Bar Inside Snack Bar

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material2

I'm wanting to add an angular material progress bar inside my angular material snackbar.  The point of the progress bar is to act as a countdown, so if the snackbar is open for 5 seconds, then over the course of the 5 seconds the progress bar goes from 100 -> 0 or something similar.

However, I'm having a bit of trouble getting the progress change to happen.  The code below is what I have in my snackbar.  Basically, every x seconds I increment the progress bar value.  This works fine in a regular component but in the snackbar the progress value stops just after it starts.

```
export class PizzaPartyComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any) { }
  intervalSubscription;
  countdown: number = 0;
  ngOnInit(){
    const source = interval(100);

    this.intervalSubscription = source.subscribe(val => {
        this.countdown += 1;
        console.log("Interval", val, " - ", this.countdown)
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("Snackbar Destoryed")
    this.intervalSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The console reads

> Interval 0  -  1
>
> Interval 0  -  2
>
> Interval 0  -  3
>
> Interval 0  -  4
>
> Interval 0  -  5

And so on until the snackbar is destroyed  ( the snackbar closes around 0 -30).

`countdown` in the code is updating fine, however, the progress bar value gets stuck early on.  If `countdown` is rendered on the screen it goes from 0 to 2 and doesn't get updated after that.  **It always does 2 loops of the interval.**  The only thing I can think of is after `ngOnInit()` finishes, then the change detection for `countdown` stops.

[image]

Comment: Not an answer - but a snackbar is not a progress dialog. Snackbars should never appear for more than 10 seconds according to Material Design specifications. Don't use snackbar for this - think of something else. Does the user really need to be watching the time and waiting? If so - then a dialog is appropriate. If not then a snackbar at the start and another when done is appropriate.

Comment: If anyone still want it readymade, here is angular 17 link: https://github.com/dheerajawale-svg/angular-snackbar

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using an observable that emits values from 0 to 100.

This observable can then be passed to the dialog and assigned to the `value` of the `mat-progress-bar`.

```js
export class SnackbarComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public progress: Observable<number>) {}
}
```

```html
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="progress | async"></mat-progress-bar>
```

When creating the snackbar, you just need to pass the `progress` observable as data and then use `progress.next(<NEW_VALUE>)` to change the progress bar.